# Regular expression to change user input

Tags: php, sql, regex, search

I am doing a search on my database. If the user enters eg. "foo bar" I want to display rows that have both "foo" AND "bar".

My SQL syntax looks like this:
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE MATCH (t1.foo_desc, t2.bar_desc) AGAINST ('+foo* +bar*')

How can I change the user input "foo bar" into "+foo* +bar*" using a regular expression in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

```
$match = '+' . implode('* +', explode(' ', $input)) . '*';
```

This assumes that the input isn't an empty string;

Edit: As @Bart S points out, str_replace (or mb_str_replace if you're dealing with multibyte characters) would be even simpler...

```
$match = '+' . str_replace(' ', '* +', $input) . '*';
```

Comment: +1 I don't understand why people always demand regular expressions for trivial tasks

Comment: A programmer has a problem. He decides to solve this using regular expressions. Now he has two problems.

Comment: +1 Thinking about it, I don't know either. ;-) However, *some* normalization/checking should be done in any case.

Comment: @metaphor: Now that's a smart quote. I've never heard it before.

Comment: Works, but explode parameters should be the other way around: explode($input, ' ') -> explode(' ', $input)

Comment: What if there are two ore more spaces between two words? Your solution would replace those additional spaces too and turn `foo  bar` (two space between) into "+foo* +* +bar*". So why not just a reg… ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `\b` and `\B` to identify the word/not-word boundaries, and thus insert your +/*.

Answer (score 1):

First, trim the user input and remove anything strange (punctuation, quotes, basically everything `"\W"`, except white space of course).

Then, substitute:

```
(?<=\w)\b
```

with

```
"*"
```

and:

```
\b(?=\w)
```

with

```
"+"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression to replace the spaces between two words by `* +`:

```
'+' . preg_replace('/\s+/', '* +', trim($input)) . '*'
```

**Edit**   Basically this is an implementation to [what Tomalak said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792695/regular-expression-to-change-user-input/792737#792737) just with `\s` instead of `\W`.